# Only 1 Texture Baking When 2 Must Be Baked [Blender]

Tags: texturing, uv, texture-painting, texture-baking, baking

I'm new to Blender. I have an issue with the texture baking. I am trying to bake 2 textures together in blender so I can use them in my Roblox game. The main problem I'm having is when I bake the 2 textures, only 1 of them comes out.

While Baking:
[image]

After Baking Is Done:
[image]

Both textures have their metallic value set to 0, and, as seen in the photos, the Direct and
Indirect contributions are turned off.

Images Of Shading Nodes (Of Both Texture Nodes) Tell me if I did something wrong:

[image]

[image]

Any help would be appreciated, Goodbye!

Comment: Hi Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that users can at a glance understand what your post is about. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid anything not strictly essential to the post. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and makes your question findable for future users. See ["*What is the problem with posting an image or link and asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: Hello, if RPaladin's answer is not correct, please pack your images and share your file

Comment: @moonboots Here ya go

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1dk_7CWuXbyXxzeK5fMTqNymcBTlyEJ8l?usp=sharing

Comment: @moonboots Sorry, try this.

https://www.mediafire.com/folder/w88tf03rr9id5/BlendFile

Comment: it's an .obj with no material, could you please share a blend file with the object and its materials?

Comment: @moonboots https://www.mediafire.com/file/lhf43dy87nbx4n2/SeweragePothole.blend/file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to:

- Put the same *Image Texture* node in both the 2 materials with a new black image, call the image *Bake* for example, keep the node selected in both the 2 materials
- Put the *Metallic* value at 0 in both the 2 materials
- Select the second UV map in the *Object Data panel > UV Maps*
- In the Bake panel choose *Diffuse* with *Direct* and *Indirect* off
- Bake

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you haven't specified which texture + UV to use in the baking process for your 2nd material. Each of your materials should have an extra Image Texture node as well as an extra UV Map node. The extra Image Texture node should have attached the image you want to bake to.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, it worked! However, when applying the baked texture to the mesh, it looks messed up. Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: Make sure the mesh with the baked image also has the UV used in the baking process. Make sure you're also not actively selecting a different UV in the mesh tab of the properties editor, otherwise it'll show your images for that mesh based on that other, actively selected UV.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work.

https://imgur.com/wBUAnDK

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: First of all, I don't see that your UV nodes have any UV data-blocks selected. Secondly, did you do this bake setup for **both** of your materials? If all else fails, please edit your initial post and include your blend file.